# GAE stackdriver debugger "The debugger could not find a debug target for the application" error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-stackdriver

I have deployed a flex aspcore app on GAE and now want to debug it. Unfortunately the stackdriver debugger page is not letting me go further with the following error

**"The debugger could not find a debug target for the application MyApplication - MyVersion"**

- I have enable debug on the instance (from the instance thumb).
- I have added source code.
- I have accessed the instance with the right url before trying to debug.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently. Make sure you have [added the debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/how-to) in the source. In my case I was using python and flask.

In `requirements.txt` I added the requirement `google-python-cloud-debugger`.

Then I added the debugging code. This could be anywhere but is suggested to be placed before creating the application.

Before my `create_app` factory function:

```
try:
  import googleclouddebugger
  googleclouddebugger.enable()
except ImportError:
  pass
```

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. Please make sure how to do it in detail rather than providing a link to a documentation. If you really wish to provide a link, please you may comment on the original question.